# Xamarin app deploys on android device but it only runs in the background

Tags: android, deployment, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I made an app in Xamarin Studio that works perfectly inside any emulator, but when I try to run it on an android phone (api level 16) or android tablet (api level 15) the program starts but it automatically goes in the background. When I try to reach for it, it tries to bring it on screen, but fails, and I am back at my home screen.

Any ideea what this misbehaviour even means? I have no errors, no warnings whatsoever.

Comment: Are you using the trial and is your app deployed over 24 hours ago?

Comment: I am using the freeware version. The app was deployed some hours ago today.

Comment: found out what was happening. the application was failing but the error logging in console wasn't really popping out for some reason. I freed some space on the device, ran it in debug mode and exceptions were thrown.